# Cant answer the phone

Tags: calls, htc-sensation-xe

Often when someone phones me, the phone just locks up. I can't slide the ring up to answer.

Sometimes the ring moves a little.. sometimes not at all. I just can't do anything until the caller stops ringing. The phone becomes responsive again and I have to call them back.

I have just upgraded to 4.0 from 2.3 and the problem is still there. I haven't rooted the phone or done anything special to it..

Apart from this the phone is always responsive and I don't really have any other problems.

How can I sort this out?

Phone: HTC Sensation-xe

Comment: Sounds like they screwed up the threading.  The phone process normally has high priority but it shouldn't be so high that it prevents you from interacting with the phone.

Comment: Try to install the rocked dial and in settings try to make it default app for receiving calls. `Settings>caller ID`

Comment: Can you catch the error message using `adb logcat` when connected to the computer?

Comment: HTC has inbuilt answering. By moving the phone into a vertical position it answers the call, if you face it towards the ground it rejects it.

Comment: @avirk, installing rocket dial does seem to have done the trick, I've had no lock up for several days now. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user said my comment helped him and post it as answer.

Try to install the [rocket dial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=intelgeen.rocketdial.pro&feature=search_result) and in settings try to make it default app for receiving calls.
 `Settings>caller ID`

Also you can use free version of [HD Caller ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.nicky.HDCallerID&hl=en) which has option to overtake the default caller screen.

Comment: Thanks. although the rocket dial app does seem to be quite messy - the default dialer shows for a second before rocket dialer kicks in - it does seem to have fixed the problem.

Comment: In `caller ID` settings you will see an option `Set the time delay for showing caller ID` and set it to `No delay` by default it has set to one second.

Comment: Your welcome :)

Comment: I updated my answer you can check it :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the phone connected to a PC/charger while you were trying the call? Try to have a good 'earth ground' at all times when handling a phone with capacitive screens.
I had the same problem when my phone was connected to the PC/charger.

If that wasn't the problem, try using a different dialer app from the market and see if that brings up the problem.

Comment: No, its not connected. Doesn't a dialer app only affect outgoing calls?

Answer (score 0):

I've read the ICS ROMs on Sensation XE were buggy. Hence they delayed the ICS ROMs for (original) Sensation to fix the bugs. (Assuming you're using stock Dialer.) Update to the latest build of ICS that's been released for your device.

Comment: I just have.. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be to root and use a custom ROM and kernel...  it's the touch screen drivers locking up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Droid 2. For me, it was a precursor to the hardware for touch interaction going haywire: it was registering other touches on the screen in a line on the right side. I was able to view them by opening a drawing program, or popping up the gesture screen in Dolphin HD. Random touches would appear up and down in a straight line.

This happened more frequently when I'd been outside working, or the phone got warm through other means.

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me on my Nexus S, running stock Gingerbread and now stock Ice Cream Sandwich, that occaisionally when I try to answer the phone the touch screen is unresponsive. I find that if I press the power button to turn off the screen (which silences the phone as well) and then turn it back on I can answer the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Its not Android problem its HTC Problem. I have experienced same problem few times. All you can hope is an upgrade of HTC Sense from HTC. Ring was introduced by HTC because there was problem with earlier approach of dragging up. Try to kill few unwanted process in your cellphone so that your becomes even more responsive.